# Understand error in R package installation

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm trying to install a package on R. I'm using RStudio Version 1.2.5033, on Mac.
But there are an error message and I don't understand what can I do to resolve this problem and therefore install this package.

```
Erreur : (converti depuis l'avis) le package ‘foreach’ a été compilé avec la version R 3.6.2 Exécution arrêtée
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘BFDA’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/BFDA’
Erreur : Failed to install 'BFDA' from GitHub:
(converti depuis l'avis) installation of package ‘/var/folders/zd/c6vlxkyx5qd8v4dg89n__4kh0000gn/T//RtmpJUwezL/file143801a73e1a7/BFDA_0.5.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: With my limited knowledge of spanish/french/italian it seems the following are valid: You need to install  [`XQuartz`](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) for compilation libraries. `foreach` is having trouble installing ofr `R-3.6.2`, and It might be easily fixed by updating to [`R-4.0.2`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-4.0.2.pkg).

Comment: @PM_cog, you should give us a bit more information:  what version of R are you using, and what command did you use to try to do the install?

Comment: I have updated my R version and that's work! Thank you for your answers.